# Does android have *native* support SVG image as drawable resources (icons)?

Tags: android, graphics, resources, android-layout, svg

I'm reading and watching UI tutorial. They all talk about the fact that you need to be aware of different devices size and resolution. Therefore export your icons into several size to support different screen density.
SVG is an open standard (W3C) that should be use to tackle this kind of problem. So can I natively use SVG file as drawable for my icons ?

N.B.: I'm NOT talking about browser support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer has changed. Since version 21, Lollipop the operating system has had support for VectorDrawable. This is added to by a support library that allows you to use VectorDrawable well back into previous versions. These include support for importing most of the important SVG vector commands and having Android Studio automatically convert them to a VectorDrawable.

Use Vector Image Assets for all versions. <strike>-- Also even in older versions it's entirely possible to do fonts. Basically you give it a font asset then load up a specific letter of the font as an icon. Since fonts are glyphs and vector glyphs at that, you can very much get vector icons pretty far back.</strike>

https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Answer (score 5):

Android does not support SVG rasterization. Look at [libsvg-android](https://launchpad.net/libsvg-android) or [svg4mobile](http://code.google.com/p/svg4mobile/). It solves that problem.

Comment: Any plan to do so ? 
– Libsvg-android is a 3rd party library
– SVG4mobile doesn't seem active anymore (last edit may 2010)

Comment: "Any plan to do so ?" -- there are no publicly-discussed plans. That being said, a Google-authored SVG library for Android can be found at http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

Comment: libsvg-android last commit was on 2010, is this project dead?

Comment: Yes, it seems like that :(